# MS Access file already in use

Tags: ms-access

When I close an access database it sometimes pops up an message saying "Could not use 'myfile.mdb'; file already in use. I click OK and it merrily closes without any fuss. Can anyone tell me what this means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have turned on *Compress when closing* under *Settings, Current Database*.

Comment: yes, I have several access database, I have turned on "Compact on Close" for all of them.
But this weird message only happens to this one particular database, and not all the time.

Comment: I would advice to turn it off - at least for this database. The reason is that - if not - you may end up with a corrupted database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Here is something interesting, I turned off <i>compress when closing</i> , then tried manually compressing. The error message <i>Could not use 'blah .mdb'; file already in use</i> comes up every time I try to compress the database. I tried updating the mdb to the latest accdb format, the problem remains. I'm starting to think the database might be a bit corrupt already.

Comment: Are you doing this off a network folder? If so, try first moving the file to, say, the Desktop, then run the repair/compact, and copy the file back to the network folder.

Comment: No, however it is in a dropbox folder. I'm starting to think the database might be corrupt.

I'll try creating a new database and importing the various tables and forms. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: At least try to move it off the dropbox folder to a "clean" local folder and repair/compact here.